# How can I select all the records that were entered/updated on the same time in multiple tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

is there someone out there who can help me select multiple records that were entered/updated on different tables on the same time in the SQL Server database. Do you think this is possible or not?

Your help is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is the data already in the database, or are you still writing the application?

Comment: the data is already in the database.

Comment: I don't think there is a general solution to your problem. The information you look for is not centrally logged, and querying every table you are interested in is your only alternative (IMHO). You could use code generation to build the necessary SQL. Can you add more detail to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Does your table have a date/time-stamp column of type DATETIME??

Otherwise you're probably out of luck....

Marc

Comment: the tables have date/time-stamp, but what I need is how would I know all the records that were entered? or updated?

Comment: Well, there's really not much you can do other than selecting from all potential tables, with a "WHERE CreatedDate = (date of interest)" and then see where you get results. There's no magic way to select from all tables for a particular date...

Answer (score 0):

Hm... could it be something as simple as

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     MyTable 
WHERE    CreatedDate = 'the date you are interested in'
```

or

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     MyTable 
GROUP BY CreatedDate
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

?

Comment: the case is, there are alot of tables, how would I know which table/tables are updated?

Answer (score 0):

if you are inside the insert trigger, you can query the `inserted` pseudo-table.

Answer (score 0):

If the DATETIME columns are all named the same, you can generate the queries like

```
select
    'select * from '
        + t.name 
        + ' where UpdateDate = ''2009-05-01''' as SelectStatement
from sys.tables as t
```

Or if the DATETIME column name is not static, you can do something along these lines:

```
select
    'select * from ' + t.name 
        + ' where ' + c.name + ' = ''2009-05-01''' as SelectStatement
from sys.tables as t join sys.columns as c on t.object_id=c.object_id
where c.system_type_id = (select system_type_id from sys.types where name = 'datetime')
```